# Flutter apk package appears to be invalid

Tags: android, flutter, installation, apk

I have been trying to build an apk using the command "flutter build apk" and the apk is building perfectly fine and I am also able to run the same on my emulator. But for some weird reason when testing on a physical device I get the following error stating that "App not installed. Package appears to be invalid.". Any sort of help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Uninstall your old app and try again

Comment: Unfortunately, I was never able to install the apk. So, there is nothing that I am able to uninstall to re-install.

Comment: On the phone activate Developer Options and Android Debug bridge (adb), connect your phone to a PC with MinimalADb or Android SDK installed and install the app using the command `adb install <apkfilename>`. Then you will get an error message why install fails..

Comment: Upon reviewing my build.gradle file, the compileSdkVersion is assigned to 33 and the targetSdkVersion is assigned as 32. Does this impact the installation of the apk in any way?

Answer (score 2):

### 100% I have faced the same problem

### Check or Configure agin your android/app/build.gradle

1. Go to =>
   https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android
2. Find the **Configure signing in gradle:**
3. follow the step agin:

### Or Go to your project location:

**[project]/android/app/build.gradle**

1. Find the **defaultConfig** section
2. Paste this code below

```html
 signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following steps :

1. flutter clean
   2.flutter pub get
2. flutter run

after flutter run, tried to install `app-debug.apk`, hopefully it will work for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).